# Compute $ \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n+1)3^{2n}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I think that I should to use the root test, but I still don't know how does it work in this case. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Do you want to show that it converges (in which case a comparison with $\sum_n \frac 1{3^{2n}}$ will do) or compute the value?

Comment: I want to compute the exact value

Comment: I see; I was confused because you mentioned the root test, which can help estabilish if a series converges or not but not its value :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\int_0^{1/\sqrt{3}} t^{4n}\,dt=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{(4n+1)3^{2n}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Taking the body of your question to be your question, the root test will do nicely
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(4n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}3^2}=\frac{1}{9}<1
$$
and the series converges.

To compute it, play the usual 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n
$$
games.

edit: now that I know you are asking for a computation of the series, I will add it for completeness: Note, setting $x=\frac{1}{3}$, your series is
the function 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{4n+1}
$$
evaluated at $x=1/3$. Note also,
$$
\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}=\int x^{4n}dx
$$
which is close to what we want. 
$$
\frac{1}{x}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}=\frac{x^{4n}}{4n+1}
$$
And 
$$
f(x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{4n}}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x}\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{4n}
$$
can you finish?

Comment: play the usual game?

Comment: @Herrpeter yes, differentiate termwise, integrating termwise, re-index etc and then plug in $x=1/3$.

Comment: Lol, the usual game!  I love it!

Comment: @Herrpeter also note, the root test is not a good place to go when you  are trying to compute a series, it only (sometimes) tells you whether some (absolutely convergent) series converge. It occurred to me this might be the source of the incongruence between your title and body

Answer (score 3):

Positive terms. Criterion of the quotient:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{(4n+5)3^{2n+2}}}{\frac{1}{(4n+1)3^{2n}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \dfrac{4n+1}{4n+5}·\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}\right)=\dfrac{1}{9}<1\ $$

$\Rightarrow$ The serie converges.